# .aJax: How to convert returned data from a service to a string

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services

I have a `webservice` call using `.ajax`. The service returns a String om success:

This is the call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ISOEmails.asmx/UpdateEmailAddress",
            data: "{'isoNum':'" + strIsoNum + "','newEmail':'" + strNewEmail + "','userName':'" + strUserName + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, status) {
                $('#MainContent_lblUpdateMessage').text("Old Email: " + JSON.stringify(data) + " New Email: " + strNewEmail);
            },
            error: function (request, status) {
                  //do something else
            }
```

On success I'm getting the `data` back in the following format when using `JSON.stringify(data)`:`{"d":"test@test.com "}`

What is the right way to return the correct `String` without all that weird notations?

Thank you

---Update---

Now when retrieving the data this way:

```
$('#MainContent_lblUpdateMessage').text("Old Email: " + (JSON.stringify(data.d)).replace('"', '') + " New Email: " + strNewEmail);
```

I somehow get the following result: `Old Email: test@test.com" New Email: newtest@test.com`

Why do I have '"' after Old Email?

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data.d` if you're sure that there is always `d` in the result.

Comment: Thank's!. It worked. But what does that mean? It is some kind of conversion?

Comment: @eugene.it This AJAX request returns JSON which is serialized JavaScript object (as seen in your JSON.stringify output). d is a property of this object so in JavaScript you can access it using data.d or data['d']. It is a normal way in JavaScript to access properties of any object.

Comment: Thank's for a good explanation, @Jakub Fedyczac. I'm new to all this and did not know `data.d` is the same as accessing the property of an object. Good to know.

Comment: I updated my post with info regarding the result I have. It does not output the way it needs to. It has an extra `"` mark

Answer (score 1):

Skip `JSON.stringify`. It adds quotations in this case. Leave:

```
$('#MainContent_lblUpdateMessage').text("Old Email: " + data.d + " New Email: " + strNewEmail);
```

BTW. Replace works only on first character found. You'll have to use regexp with `g` flag to replace all occurrences. Like:

```
x.replace(/"/g, '')
```